# Pentaho Data integration transformation, Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory not set

Tags: filepath, pentaho, data-integration

I'm trying to use the built-in `Internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory` variable. I take as an example a simple sample the Pentaho Data Integration provides,`CSV Input - Reading customer data with error logging.ktr`.

Here is the tooltip after CTRL+SPACE in a variable aware field:

[image: Correct variable value]

However I do exactly the same as in the sample my variable has no value:

[image: Missing variable value]

Any ideias? I've briefly checked Pentaho forum however the only related issue I found does not seem to answer my question.

I'm using Ubuntu and PDI version 4.2.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is normal behavior, **in a repository you have no reference
> directory to use**.
>
> There are no relative paths in a repository, so **best practice would
> simply be to define a variable indicating a file location**.  That way
> you can make this configurable for the various places where the
> repository is being used.

*in [PDI-7199](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-7199), thanks to Matt Casters*

Answer (score 0):

Is your transformation actually saved?   I wonder if you forgot to save it - in that case it wouldnt be set.

Alternatively you're not in a job are you? the variable name is different for a job.

Comment: Yes it's saved, in a file based repository. No I'm not in a job. I just check if I open the Kettle repository in Windows has the same result and yes, te result it's the same. I wonder if it might have something with the file based repository thing... I choose this option because it's easier to integrate into a VCS like git.

Comment: no, it's not that, that definately works.  Ok, so just if it's not set in spoon - is it set at runtime? run your transform, i'm pretty sure it'll be set?

Comment: No luck there also, I already had tried that but with your comment I went for it again an double check it. However I did save a transformation outside the repository and the path it's available and works. What version of PDI do you have?

Comment: 4.2.1 hmm.  is this an EE repository or a normal database repository?  maybe it's something quirky about your java version? (Just a total guess now!)

Comment: Normal FILE repository, not using database, facilitates my Git integration. Rechecked java installation, all seems normal. I have been talking to a friend and he also has the exact same problem. So I'm opening a ticket in Pentaho tracker and wait for a inside response. Thank for your attention by btw.